# How to Set DNS Suffix and Registration using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, dns

I am writing a script to automatically set the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" & "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS" in Advanced TCP/IP Settings on a fresh out of the box device.

I've been successful clicking through the Network Settings prior to running the script in order for those settings to be set. I want to avoid doing that at all cost.

This is my code.

```
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "*" -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
Get-NetAdapter -name "*" | Set-DnsClient -UseSuffixWhenRegistering $True
```

When I run this code in powershell only the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" box is checked not the "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS" box.

Comment: Please describe the problem you're facing. Does something about your code not work the way you expected? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. I tend to use the WMI method. First thing to do is get all the adapters that are IP Enabled. Once you have this then all you need to do is use the SetDynamicDNSRegistration Method. This method takes two Overloads both are Boolean and map to the two check boxes (Register this connection's addresses in DNS and Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS). The below example would check the **Register this connection's addresses in DNS** box and uncheck the **Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS** box"

```
$adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 'True'"
$adapters.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($true,$false)
```

This example would result in both boxes being checked:

```
$adapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 'True'"
$adapters.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($true,$true)
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to set those values when the card is DISCONNECTED? (IpEnabled = false) ? We need to do it in our environement but on VPN adapters....

Comment: @Rakha, if ip enable = false the only way that you could do this is via the registry. This should be a setting in your VPN software though. If you must do it via the registry and cannot find the key take a snapshot before and after and compare the two to see which key/value changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue.

When setting 'Use this connection's DNS suffix' through the Set-DNSClient cmdlet it appears to run successfully. Running the Get-DNSClient cmdlet shows the the setting being correctly adjusted but the related registry key is not created nor is the GUI updated.

Key - HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TCPIP\Paramters\Interfaces\
Property - RegisterAdapterName

[Adapter - IPV4 Properties - Advanced - DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMqce.png)

During testing I have noticed that after the key is created, either through the WMI code above, REGEDIT or the GUI, the PowerShell cmdlets do correctly amend the registry key/gui.

I have resorted to using code similar to the example provided by DaSmokeDog to force the creation of the registry keys for a given adapter then return to using the simple PowerShell cmdlets afterwards.

Not ideal having to work this way but my (limited) testing shows it working.